# Proper way of using the Cancellation Token with Delay in C#

Tags: c#, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I cannot figure out how to this right. In a forever loop, I have a switch case depending on an event. Let's say Case A, B, and C in that order. When I reach "A" a task `HandleCommand` should be cancelled. But when I reach "C", the `HandleCommand` should be started.
The `HandleCommand` has a delay of 10 seconds, if the loop gets to the case "A" before the delay finishes, this `HandleCommand` should be cancelled. Then when I reach C, the `HandleCommand` starts.

```
private static CancellationTokenSource ctr = null;
private static CancellationToken token;

private static void QueueListener(object portNumber)
{
    try
    {
        do
        {
            if (QueueType == "1")
            {
                switch (_entryState)
                {
                    case A:
                        _entryState = B;
                        if (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        {
                            ctr.Cancel();
                        }
                        break;
                    case B:
                        _entryState = C;
                        break;
                    case C:
                        try
                        {
                            ctr = new CancellationTokenSource();
                            token = ctr.Token;
                            Task.Run(() => HandleCommand(token));
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("A has been reached. " +
                                "Command to standby has been cancelled.");
                            ctr?.Dispose();
                        }
                        finally
                        {

                        }
                        _entryState = A;
                        break;
                }
            }
        } while (true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex);
    }
}

private static void HandleRfidStandbyCommand(CancellationToken token)
{
    //...
    Task.Delay(10000).Wait();
    //...
    ctr.Dispose();
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    };
}
```

With this code, on the first run, the `ctr` will be null in case "A" since it only gets instantiated on case "C". Also when it reaches case "C" and the `HandleCommand` starts and waits for 10 seconds, even when I get to case "A", the task `HandleCommand` does not exit. It still waits for the completion.

Comment: You didn't pass the `token` to Delay. Call `Task.Delay(10000, token)`. But this will raise an `OperationCancelledException` and `ctr.Dispose` is never reached. The code looks weird. There is a running Task that waits for the timeout - but it violates [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Try to make both methods async and use a `using`-statement to release `cts`. For more inforation see [Stephen Cleary on Cancellation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2022/02/cancellation-1-overview.html).

Comment: Actually, passing the token to the Task.Delay did the trick.